# Which real-world UWP Apps use AppServices?

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

Are there any real-world UWP applications (other than the demos on github and in the docs) that offer services as [App Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service) and can be addressed by other applications using AppServiceConnection? If yes, which ones and where can their docs that describe the parameters of the communication be found?

All the following applications declare in their manifests that they offer app services:

- Microsoft.MicrosoftOfficeHub_8wekyb3d8bbwe
- Microsoft.OneConnect_8wekyb3d8bbwe
- Microsoft.3DBuilder_8wekyb3d8bbwe
- Microsoft.Microsoft3DViewer_8wekyb3d8bbwe
- Microsoft.WindowsFeedbackHub_8wekyb3d8bbwe
- Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy
- Microsoft.WebMediaExtensions_8wekyb3d8bbwe
- Microsoft.ScreenSketch_8wekyb3d8bbwe
- Microsoft.Windows.Photos_8wekyb3d8bbwe
- Microsoft.HEVCVideoExtension_8wekyb3d8bbwe
- Microsoft.XboxApp_8wekyb3d8bbwe
- Microsoft.Office.OneNote_8wekyb3d8bbwe
- Microsoft.People_8wekyb3d8bbwe
- Microsoft.WindowsMaps_8wekyb3d8bbwe
- Microsoft.WindowsAlarms_8wekyb3d8bbwe
- Microsoft.XboxGamingOverlay_8wekyb3d8bbwe
- Microsoft.ZuneMusic_8wekyb3d8bbwe
- Microsoft.ZuneVideo_8wekyb3d8bbwe
- Microsoft.MixedReality.Portal_8wekyb3d8bbwe
- Microsoft.WindowsStore_8wekyb3d8bbwe
- Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe
- Microsoft.SkypeApp_kzf8qxf38zg5c
- Microsoft.YourPhone_8wekyb3d8bbwe

But I could not find out any docs, any other apps using them or any other way to find out the used parameters!
Could someone help on this?

Answer (score 1):

I have added an [app service](https://github.com/mscherotter/TopographicService) to my app [Topographic](https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9nblggh5xrh3) so that you can create a 3D printable topographic model of anywhere given lat/long data.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone remember Windows Phones?
On them, the Photos app was the default "Picture Picker" if an app or website requested the user to upload a picture...
Additionally, you had the option to "Take a picture", which opened the Camera app instead.
Later on Windows 10 Mobile, the Files app could also be used for this purpose.

In Windows 10 (Desktop), these can still be used, but most of the time File Explorer just openens for everything.

**Microsoft.XboxGamingOverlay_8wekyb3d8bbwe**
This one is what they call the "Game Bar", which launches when you press `Win + G`

Etc, etc...

Currently not all of them probably use the App Service declaration, but you get the point :)

I think the most used application of the declaration would be a "File Explorer"-like app